# Find $f(v)$ in: $4 \pi = \int_{0}^{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{ \pi }f(v)\sin(v)dvdu$

Tags: calculus

How would $f(v)$ be found in the following equation :

$$4 \pi = \int_{0}^{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{ \pi }f(v)\sin(v)dvdu$$

Comment: did you notice that there is no $u$ is the equation?

Comment: What makes you think it's possible to find $f$ from that equation? Do you think you could find $g$ from $\int_0^1g(x)\,dx=17$? or from $g(7)=3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simplifies to $\int_0^\pi f(v)\sin v\ dv=2$. There are infinitely many solutions, for example $f=1$.